# Should we use `else return` or `return`?

Tags: if-statement, language-agnostic, return

When we make a function that returns a boolean, should we return on every if/else statment or not?

For example, if you wanted to check that a file existed in swift, you would do

```
func fileExists() -> Bool
{
    if let dir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first
    {
        let path = dir.appendingPathComponent("\(self.name).\(self.type)")
        if(FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: path.path))
        {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

The question is, should we add `return false` at the end of the function if the condition was met as shown above, or should we add `return false` on each `if` statment (shown below)

```
func fileExists() -> Bool
{
    if let dir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first
    {
        let path = dir.appendingPathComponent("\(self.name).\(self.type)")
        if(FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: path.path))
        {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

To me, the first example looks cleaner, however I am not sure that this is good practice. Even though it looks cleaner, I would like to use the best/safest way instead, so this question is not an opinion on what looks the best.

Comment: Is this question language-specific ? If so, please add the suitable language tag.

Comment: @Quentin This is not language-specific. I would like to know for other languages as well since I am also using java too. The example given was just becase I was working on that project at the time.

Comment: Please take a look here http://refactoring.com/catalog/replaceNestedConditionalWithGuardClauses.html

Comment: In this specific case, `if (X) { return true } else { return false }` can just be replaced by `return X`.

Comment: There are two general guidelines in cases like this (1)  does the code behave as intended?   (2)   can a mere mortal understand that it is behaving as intended?      The specific answers to both questions depend, to some extent, on the programming language (what it requires or what it doesn't) and on coding guidelines (i.e. that the programmer is following to maximise ease of understanding the code).

Comment: @Peter So fo you mean that as long as the code works and can be understood, it does not matter?

Comment: Indeed.  Code that doesn't work right is pointless.  Code that can be misunderstood, even if it works right, is equally pointless - because someone who misunderstands it may later change it so it doesn't work right.

Comment: This is opinion based. My opinion is I would heavily deride code of the second style. Using an `if` to then just return `true` or `false` sends shivers down my spine and bile up my gullet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question almost looks like a pure opinion-based one. But I do know of a general function pattern that includes the answer to your question.

A function should:

- Validate its parameters;
- *Then* do its task, taking care of error handling and bailing out if it cannot succeed;
- *Then* compute and return its result.

The result is a very linear control flow, with no more nesting than necessary. Applying this guideline to your code:

```
func fileExists() -> Bool
{
    //If path exists, the variable dir will have a value. If not, bail out
    guard let dir = FileManager.default.urls(
        for: .documentDirectory,
        in: .userDomainMask
    ).first else {
        return false
    }

    let path = dir.appendingPathComponent("\(self.name).\(self.type)")

    // if(...) { return true; } else { return false; } pattern factored out
    return FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: path.path)
}
```

Comment: Also by doing it like this, it allows me to do what Robert C. Martin says in his Clean Code book. Functions should only have one indentation level, max two. This allows me to keep most the code at one indentation level.

Answer (score 0):

Both examples would return "true" ONLY if the condition

```
if(FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: path.path))
```

is met.

As this is the only way of returning "true", I'd go with the first example, for simplicity and readability.
The "else"-blocks are unnecessary as your function will inevitably return "false" if the condition mentioned above is not met.

Answer (score -3):

Although Both will work fine here but u should use else return for better practice. Its more secure than the first one and it will increase your future scope of the code also

Comment: How is it more secure?

Comment: What do you mean by "it will increase your future scope"?